# solve $\sqrt{z^2+4t}=w$ for $z\in\mathbb C$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Let $t\ge0$ and $z,w\in\mathbb R$. We obviusly find the two solutions $z=\pm\sqrt{w^2-4t}$ when we solve $\sqrt{z^2+4t}=w$ for $z$. But are there more solutions Wien $z,w\in\mathbb C$ instead? Howard do we approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Square root is generally defined to be a number, which squared, gives the thing below the root. So your equation is essentially equivalent to
$$z^2+4t=w^2.$$
Because we want to solve it for $z$ and $t$ and $w$ are treated as known parameters, we can conveniently rewrite the equation into
$$z^2=w^2-4t,$$
and we just need to take this square root of the right hand side. Every complex number has $2$ square roots except the $0$ which has only one square root - itself. All you need to check is whether or not $w^2-4t$ is equal to $0$. That tells about the number of solutions. Finding the actual square root in the complex field is a method. And there are surely many methods to do it. The ones that are specifically designed for complex case and are meaningless in the real case are maybe the ones in which we represent complex numbers as expressions with real parameters, such as $z=a+ib$ or $z=re^{i\varphi}$ ($a,b,r$ and $\varphi$ are real numbers). Then the square root of $z$ is reduced to square roots of real numbers which you are familiar with: $z=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\varphi}{2}}=\sqrt{r}(\cos(\frac{\varphi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{\varphi}{2}))=\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}e^{\frac{i}{2}\arctan(\frac{b}{a})}.$ You can simplify the expressions of course.